# Laravel 4 Blade Templating

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've experienced an problem. When I used lets say `<script src="js/app.js"></script>` and things like that it was returning the error when I inspected element and went onto console in chrome, but atleast the dropdown and the scripts worked. When I changed to things like:

```
{{ HTML::script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/prettify.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('js/scripts.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/jquery.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-button.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js') }}
```

it wouldn't work. there is no console errors when I inspect element, but the site won't load it for some reason. Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Can you make your question little bit more understanding?its bit unclear what you are asking

Comment: is the typo after `{{ HTML::script('js/scripts.js') }}` is just here or in your code also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Jquery
{{ HTML::script('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js') }}
// Your's scripts
{{ HTML::script('/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('/js/prettify.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('/js/scripts.js') }}
// Twitter bootstrap
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-transition.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-alert.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-modal.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tab.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-tooltip.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-popover.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-button.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-collapse.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-typeahead.js') }}
```

---

*If the problem is still, please give a screenshot of the debugger - laravel.*

Comment: I've changed it, but no luck, still doesn't work. How could I debug? I've got an loic-sharma profiler downloaded. Also, there are no console errors in Chrome developer tools, but when I use the <script> function or w/e it works then, but it shows hell lotta errors.

Comment: To use this syntax the name of file in views must be `yourname.blade.php`. So... do you have?

Comment: I have it in the folder under views called aac.

Comment: which files are not loaded?

Comment: @Trying Tobemyself Rahul
these JS aren't loaded. I've checked, there are no errors in the Chrome developer tools console, but it isn't loaded. When I use the script (<script src=".."></script>) then there are errors in the console but they are loaded.

Comment: @Maciej Czyżewski
still not working.. I've never experienced this kind of problem:s

Comment: @core_m when you use HTML::script.....check the page source ,did you see script tags

Comment: @core_m when you use `<script></script>` tag what errors are you getting

Comment: @Trying Tobemyself Rahul
I found why it's not working. Bootstrap has updated to version 3, so there is no longer a working github pages like that. I have to point to the new pages. Thanks for the help:)